# If $(\text{id}_A\otimes \text{ev}_x)(z)= 0$ for all $x \in X$. Do we have $z=0$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra (not necessarily unital). Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. We can consider the minimal $C^*$-tensor product $A \otimes C(X)$. On this space, we can consider the slice map
$$\text{id}_A\otimes \text{ev}_x: A \otimes C(X) \to A: a \otimes f \mapsto f(x)a$$

Suppose that $(\text{id}_A\otimes \text{ev}_x)(z)= 0$ for all $x \in X$. Do we have $z=0$?

We can also further extend the slice map further on the multiplier $C^*$-algebra

$$\text{id}_A\otimes \text{ev}_x: M(A \otimes C(X)) \to M(A)$$

Is the same (stronger) statement still true?

If $z$ is an algebraic tensor this is easy: write $z= \sum_i a_i \otimes f_i$ where the $a_i$'s are chosen to be linearly independent. Then from the assumption we have $\sum_i f_i(x) a_i = 0$ for all $x \in X$ and hence by linear independence $f_i = 0$ for all $i$ whence  $z=0$. But I don't see how to treat the cases that $z \in A \otimes C(X)$ or $z \in M(A \otimes C(X))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

For $A\otimes C(X)$ we have the standard identification with $C(X,A)$ the space of (bounded) continuous maps $X\rightarrow A$ with the sup norm.  Here $a\otimes f$ is identified with the function $x\mapsto f(x)a$.  Then $(\operatorname{id}_A\otimes \operatorname{ev}_x)$ is identified with the map $C(X,A)\rightarrow A$ given by evaluation at $x$.  The result follows.

For a proof, see [Theorem II.9.4.4 in Blackadar's book](https://packpages.unr.edu/media/1224/cycr.pdf) and references therein.  A simple proof can be found in [Ryan's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-3903-4).  I am not aware of an elementary proof online; but comments are very welcome!

For the multiplier algebra case, there is the (less standard) identification of $M(A\otimes C(X)) = M(C(X,A))$ with the space of bounded, strictly-continuous maps $X\rightarrow M(A)$.  I am afraid I am now aware of a good reference; but the proof is not so hard if you understand the proof that $A\otimes C(X) \cong C(X,A)$.  Anyway, once you have this identification, the result also follows.

---

Here's a more abstract argument.  Let $A,B$ be $C^*$-algebras and consider the tensor product $A\otimes B$.  If we assume $A$ or $B$ is *nuclear* then it doesn't matter which tensor product I choose; otherwise I will assume the *minimal* tensor product.  Let $X\subseteq B^*$ be a subset which has weak$^*$-dense linear span.  We will show that for $z\in A\otimes B$, if $(\operatorname{id}_A\otimes\phi)(z) = 0$ for all $\phi\in X$, then $z=0$.

By construction of the minimal tensor product, we may suppose there are Hilbert spaces $H,K$ so that $A\subseteq\mathcal B(H)$ and $B\subseteq\mathcal B(H)$, and then $A\otimes B$ can be identified with the norm-closed linear span of operators $a\otimes b$ in $\mathcal B(H\otimes K)$, for $a\in A,b\in B$.

For such a $z\in A\otimes B$ we have that
$$ 0 = \omega_{\xi,\eta}\big( (\operatorname{id}_A\otimes\phi)(z) \big)
= \phi\big( (\omega_{\xi,\eta}\otimes\operatorname{id}_B)(z) \big). $$
(Notice there is a bit of circularity here: to even *define* what $\operatorname{id}_A\otimes\phi$ is, I need this sort of argument.)
This holds for all $\phi\in X$ so by weak$^*$ linear density, it follows that $(\omega_{\xi,\eta}\otimes\operatorname{id}_B)(z)=0$ for all $\xi,\eta$.  A similar argument then establishes that
$$ z(\xi\otimes\alpha)=0 \qquad (\xi\in H, \alpha\in K). $$
That is, $z=0$.

Comment: To my knowledge, the first proof that $M(C_0(X,A))$ can be realised as the algebra of norm-bounded, strictly continuous function $X \to M(A)$ is Corollary 3.4 in [Akemann, Charles A.; Pedersen, Gert K.; Tomiyama, Jun Multipliers of C∗-algebras. J. Functional Analysis 13 (1973), 277–301]

Comment: @Matthew Daws. Thanks for the answer! I should have thought of the identification $C(X,A) = A \otimes C(X)$. In Murphy's text on $C^*$-algebras, this isomorphism is also proven.

Comment: @Matthew Daws. Nice answer! (+1) I did not write down the details, but it appears to me that the second part of your answer also could work for the multiplier algebras if you embedded $A \otimes B \subseteq M(A \otimes B) \subseteq B(H \otimes K)$ and then you play with the inner product on $H \otimes K$ to get the result there.

Comment: @MathQED: I think you need to be careful: for example, just because $X\subseteq B^*$ is weak$^*$-dense, is it true that $X$ separates points of $M(B)$?  That's true for the special case when $X=\{\delta_s:s\in S\} \subseteq C_0(S)^*$ but I don't think it's true in general.